# Omit false and undefined - can only omit false

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to get out of a collection only the keys where a certain prop is defined and true.
I can omit the one that arre false but not the ones where the prop is not defined.

How can I achive that?

```
type WithOptional = {
    optional?: boolean
}

type RecordWithOptional = Record<PropertyKey, WithOptional>

type OmitUndefinedAndFalseKeys<T extends RecordWithOptional> = {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key]['optional'] extends false
        ? never
        : T[key]['optional'] extends undefined ? never : key
}[keyof T]

type test = OmitUndefinedAndFalseKeys<{
    a: {optional: false}
    b: {optional: true}
    c: {}
}> // 'b' | 'c' but expected 'b' only
```

playground [link](https://tsplay.dev/w2vxrw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave out the property, its type is [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown), not `undefined`.  Instead of filtering *out* `false` and `unknown`, it's probably easier to filter *in* `true`:

```
type SelectTrueKeys<T extends RecordWithOptional> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]['optional'] extends true ? K : never
}[keyof T]

type Test = SelectTrueKeys<{
    a: { optional: false }
    b: { optional: true }
    c: {}
}> // 'b'
```

Of course there are likely to be edge cases, and other approaches entirely, but this works for the example as given in the question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgeTMOB7AdgQwDZQC8UA3gFBSVQZqa54D8AXFAEYYZ4Q5ZkC+ZMqEhQAShADGGAE4ATeElTps+ImMkzZAHgAK0mhGmgA0hBAAaWAhS0VeAHyCh4aAGUIXCcAAq0gK4QpiAAzlreUBAAHsAQWLLB6lJyCjbK9PZq5FRQANrGUHBYUADWZhgAZlDeALos3nnVOQDkNGn4TdUR0bHxUMD+0AxQ+SxYEABuhvw5pSAVVdWCwtDeEMHAau6ePgNBoVlUOCwk1Lb0LOX4wdAC2azHp214LP0BULdUEscCfBkA9H8oE1WE0oGQgA)